# C# MongoDB MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: '' cannot use element name '' because it is already being used by property '' of type ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, inheritance, serialization

I have the following Datamodel: (working in C# with MongoDB)

```cs
public class aClass
{
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class aClassDao
{
    public override string Content { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class MongoDbContext
{
    public IMongoDatabase Database { get; }
    public IMongoCollection<aClassDao> Classes=> Database.GetCollection<aClassDao>("Classes");

    public MongoDbContext()
    {
        // some connection logic
    }
}
```

When I start my application, I get the following error:

```cs
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: The property 'Content' of type 'aClassDao' cannot use element name 
'Content' because it is already being used by property 'Content' of type 'aClass'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way based on this post
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/bsonserializationexception-when-inheriting-from-domain-object-class/159341

In the end, I go with automapper solution, it is more straight forward.

Basically just need to create a new object that matching the type of the collection